# Unrendered characters in oh-my-posh prompt

Tags: git, powershell, powershell-core, windows-terminal

I have just installed oh-my-posh on PowerShell Core 7.1.1 on Windows, and I'm using PowerShell in Windows Terminal. After switching to a git repository, the prompt shows like this:
[image]
Some characters are shown as boxes which should be triangles and the branch character like
[image]
I'm currently using `Cascadia` font, and have tried `Meslo LG M Regular` and a few other fonts, but nothing works.

I've also set the encoding to UTF-8, and I can type Unicode characters in the command line and they are displayed correctly.

How can I resolve the missing square box font?

Comment: I would recommend posting as a GitHub issue for that project: [https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh3/issues](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh3/issues)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

- if you haven't already, update oh-my-posh to version 3: `Update-Module -Name oh-my-posh -Scope CurrentUser`
- download and install `Caskaydia Cove Nerd Font` font from: https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads
- in you PowerShell profile (*Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1*), set a theme like this one: `Set-PoshPrompt Powerline` (previously *Set-Theme Powerline*; you can press Tab key to cycle between available themes)
- in Windows Terminal settings, set the default font like this:

```json
"profiles": {
        "defaults": {
            // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles.
            "fontFace": "CaskaydiaCove NF",
            "fontSize": 12
        },
}
```