# VSCode and Windows Terminal Preview

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've seen people using the cmd of their choice in VSCode but I am not sure if it's just a VSCode extension or just an implementation of the local application

Can someone shed some light ?

an example
[image]

Comment: it looks like bash/zsh shell with custom prompt

Comment: @marzelin any idea how to achieve that ?

Comment: you can get something similar from here: https://github.com/justjanne/powerline-go

Comment: Very likely to be using zsh and its various features/extensions, https://opensource.com/article/18/9/tips-productivity-zsh Tons of guides around the internet on zsh customization, and then you set zsh as default for VSCode. Use a search engine please, and a new world awaits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To customize Windows Terminal and the terminal in VS Code, with Powershell (7.x) you can, for instance, use [Oh my Posh](https://ohmyposh.dev/).

In your terminal, run:

```
Install-Module posh-git -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module oh-my-posh -Scope CurrentUser
Install-Module -Name Terminal-Icons -Repository PSGallery
```

Then, create your profile.ps1 if you have not already:

```
New-item –type file –force $profile
```

And add to your profile ([location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.1#the-profile-files)):

```
Import-Module posh-git
Import-Module oh-my-posh
Import-Module -Name Terminal-Icons
Set-Theme Powerline  # Or any other theme
```

*Tip: type 'Get-PoshThemes' at prompt to see available themes*

Then, get a font with a Powerline Glyph version and set it as default in terminal settings. If you need guidance to do so, refer to that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67054886/11246056